# How to make app pluggable by add/remove a plugin file?

Tags: c#, plugins

Assume I have a plugin interface like this:

```
// PluginInterface.cs
interface Plugin
{
    bool Check_When_Loaded(string q);
}

static class PluginList
{
    public static List<Plugin> list = new List<Plugin>();
}
```

And I use it in MainWindow.cs:

```
// MainWindow.cs
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var p in PluginList.list)
    {
        if (p.Check_When_Loaded(q.Text)) break;
    }
}
```

Assume I write a plugin `LovelyPlugin.cs`:

```
// LovelyPlugin.cs
class LovelyPlugin : Plugin
{
    public bool Check_When_Loaded(string q)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I need is when I add `LovelyPlugin.cs` to C# project then complie, a 'LovelyPlugin' instance is added automaticly to `PluginList.list`, and if I remove this file then complie, there is no trace of `LovelyPlugin` in application at all.

I have a C# solution that have some simliar project (Light, Standard, Extra,...). All the difference between them is one have or doesn't have some plugin file. All `.cs` files is *add as link* to all these project and I want to build all these project concurently.

I can use `#define` and `#if` condition then build each project seperately. But I wonder if there is any way to fit my need just **by add/remove plugin file without make any change in other source code file for each project**. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wow!! First fun question I've seen in weeks :).

Comment: Wouldn't the point of a plugin be that it is compiled in its own separate assembly and loaded at runtime, instead of needing to recompile the project? Otherwise you can just link source code files in Visual Studio...

Comment: @RonBeyer: it should be. But I consider my app need and only need a set of plugins I already write and I want to make, for example, 3-5 version at complie time

Comment: You could create a custom tool that examines the output of the build and generates this list, then either set the custom tool property for the .cs file or run a post-build event that looks at the assembly and generates the .list file.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the list though, if all the plugins are in the same project you can examine the project through reflection for all types that implement `Plugin`, and generate the list runtime instead of compile time.

Comment: @RonBeyer, that is a solution. I see that Rob Davis's answer is pretty fit my need, and simple enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx)...

Start by referencing System.ComponentModel.Composition

Read up on the MEF documentation regarding Imports and Exports. In your case, the Plugins are "Exports". We can use the [InheritedExport] attribute to allow every concrete object that implements IPlugin to be exportable.

```
// IPlugin.cs

using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

[InheritedExport]
public interface IPlugin
{
    bool Check_When_Loaded(string q);
}
```

Your concrete implementation of IPlugin doesn't change.

```
// LovelyPlugin.cs

class LovelyPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public bool Check_When_Loaded(string q)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I eliminated your static PluginList class to simplify the example. Below you can see how the Main Form is "Importing" any implmentations of IPlugin found in the Assembly. If you add (or remove) additional concrete implementations of IPlugin and recompile, the list will reflect accordingly.

```
// MainWindow.cs

using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Reflection;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [ImportMany]
    public List<IPlugin> list = new List<IPlugin>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void WindowLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        container.ComposeParts(this);

        foreach (var p in list)
        {
            if (p.Check_When_Loaded(this.Name)) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant solution. For other people use your code, I suggest you add `using System.ComponentModel.Composition;` to `IPlugin.cs` and 
`using System.ComponentModel.Composition; using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;` to `MainWindow.cs`

Comment: @TuyenTk - glad this solution was useful to you! As you suggested, I edited the code sample to include the relevant using statements.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `PluginList` class:

```
// using System.Reflection;
static PluginList()
{
    list.AddRange(
        from t in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(PluginList)).GetTypes()
        where t.IsClass && t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(Plugin))
        select new Func<Plugin>(() => {
            try
            {
                return (Plugin)t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(new object[] { });
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        })());
}
```

Essentially at runtime this will:

1. Get all types in the current project (the `from` line).
2. Filter these types to only include classes that implement your `Plugin` interface (the `where` line).
3. It attempts to construct one of each of these plugin classes with a default constructor (zero-argument) in the `select` line. If you want exceptions for failed constructors, you can simply change the `return null;`.
4. Add all such constructed plugins to your list.